# Asking runtime permission when app loading

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to read one file on app starting/loading. I have written code to ask permission on `MainActivity`'s `OnStart` method

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    base.OnStart();
    const string permission = Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage;
    if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, permission) != Permission.Granted)
    {
        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Permission Granted!!!");
    }
}
```

But above code is getting **executing too late**, before that file reading is getting executed(in MainPageViewModel) and throwing exception after that asking permissions(showing popup box).

File reading code in `MainViewModel`'s constructor

```
public MainPageViewModel()
{
    GetValues();
}
public static void GetValues()
{
    try
    {
        string dataFolderPath = DependencyService.Get<IDataHelper>().DataFolderPath;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(dataFolderPath);
        XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/obj/credentials");
        _userName = node.Attributes["userName"].Value;
        _userPassword = node.Attributes["password"].Value;
        _tenantCode = node.Attributes["Code"].Value;
        _host = node.Attributes["host"].Value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

How can I first give permissions and execute subsequent code?

Comment: Request method called in onStart(). And it will not wait for open onCreate. So init your view model after permission accept callback.

Comment: I am not getting your point in 2nd sentence. Thank you.

Comment: initialize MainPageViewModel() only if you have permission .

Comment: I want to tell you that init/call your viewmodel class when permission accepted. When you are calling ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions and you will get a callback that show you permission is granted or not. Then there you will init/ call your viemodel.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your function

```
public MainPageViewModel()
{
GetValues();
}
```

to

```
public MainPageViewModel()
{
if((ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(context, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == Permission.Granted)
        && (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(context, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) == Permission.Granted))
 GetValues();
}
```

Also you can use

```
ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(Context, permission) == (int) Permission.Granted.
```

> Check permissions every time before accessing a permission related operation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't think I can I write Android code in my ViewModel because that is shared code project of xamarin.forms.

Comment: @r15 but you can pass context, or anything to constructor/ as parameter to methods, which will meet your need also check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using android library DEXTER for run time app permission or you can hard code it. And also try to fetch the app permission in onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin : https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

Check permission:

```
PermissionStatus status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync<CalendarPermission>();
```

Request permission:

```
PermissionStatus status = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<CalendarPermission>();
```